# Function that asks a ~special~ something and returns an answer

Tags: r, string, if-statement, user-input

I want to do it, but so far all I have is:

```
print("Will you go out with me?")
```

I want the code to work so that one can answer *yes/no* and if answer is *yes* then a message would return saying like the time, place, etc.

The person I am asking is an R guru so it would mean a lot to them ~~(:

Would love some help. Trying to get that date!

Comment: crossover with https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: but I don't know any Jackies

Answer (score 6):

Put the following into a file and then ask your friend to source the file.

```
r <- readline("Will you go out with me? (respond 'yes' or 'no'): ")
if(grepl("[Yy]es", r)) {
    cat("Date: 3/10/2018", "Time: 7pm", "Place: McDonalds", sep = "\n")
} else {
    cat("Too bad, I'm a catch.")
}
```

Now your friend sources the file and BOOM, date!

```
> source('~/.active-rstudio-document')
Will you go out with me?: yes
Date: 3/10/2018
Time: 7pm
Place: McDonalds
```

... or BOOM, rejected!

```
> source('~/.active-rstudio-document')
Will you go out with me?: no
Too bad, I'm a catch.
```

Comment: Might be good to have some kind of safety for `YES!` answers :)

Comment: Good call.  Added a `grepl` for checking, although it's probably best to do `readline("Will you go out with me? (respond 'yes' or 'no'): ")`

Comment: As you can tell, I'm pretty classy with my restaurant choices.

Comment: Amazing!! How'd you know my plan for date/time/place? Is that the standard first date? Didn't even know--but thank you!!!

Comment: @JackieVazquez Now find the way to hide the source code, so they can't be put off by "classy" restaurant choices before answering.